# Web api is translated to the wrong port specified in launchSettings.json

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

If I launch the web api from visual studio, it accepts requests at the address and port I specified in the launchSettings.json file. But if I run the application not from IDE, but via .exe, the api is translated to the default address and port (http://localhost:5000).

The question is, how can I launch api via .exe, but it should be translated to the address and port I need.

I am really new to asp.net web api development and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the ports are different might be that you're launching your API on IIS Express profile from Visual Studio, but when you launch it via `.exe` it runs on Kestrel.
It is recommended to run on Kestrel, so you might try to switch your launch profile to it in the VS. Then you will run on a port 5000 (unless you change it) but it will be consistent for both launching from VS and via `.exe`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-8.0#development-and-launchsettingsjson

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't need the ports to be the same, to run through VS I can always change the port, but how do I change the port to run through exe. Which profile in launchSettings does it work through? I don't even have any mention of port 5000 anywhere in the launchSettings file, even though it launches through it

Comment: Port 5000 is the default part for Kestrel. You can change it via an environment variable or  configs in appsettings.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-8.0#specify-ports-only

Comment: I added an endpoint with port 5005 for Kestrel in launchSettings, but when running via exe I still have port 5000(( Does this exe address the launchSettings file if it's just next to it?

Comment: lauchSettings.json is only for Visual Studio so it doesn't get picked up when you ryn via exe. Please try to change it in appsettings instead as said in the docs from my previous comment.

Comment: Yes, that really helped, thank you very much